# How do I get headers from a 401 Server Error

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

I'm writing a port scanner to detect web services running on the local network. Some of these web services require basic authentication - I don't know the username/ password for these services, I just want to list them, so I can't provide the credentials at this stage. I'm using the code:

```
                    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://" + req);
                    request.Referer = "";
                    request.Timeout = 3000;
                    request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0";
                    request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
                    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Head;

                    HttpWebResponse response = null;

                    try
                    {
                        response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
                        // I want to parse the headers here for the server name but as the exception is thrown the response object is null.

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        //401 error is caught here - response is null
                    }
```

I'm then parsing out the server name from the headers that are returned - I know they are being returned because I can see them with fiddler but the HttpWebResponse object is set to null as the GetResponse() method is throwing an exception. Basically - how do I get it to not throw and exception but return the headers along with a status code of 401.

Comment: Do you have control over the web services? More specifically, do you have control over their code? Moreover, 'port scanner' has nothing to do with HTTP maybe try using the TCPClient class.

Comment: no i don't have control over the web services - i'm looking for IP cameras, so i'm looking specifically for web servers. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you catch a `WebException` you'll have access to `ex.Response` and you can retrieve your headers from there.

Comment: NOTE: This is undefined behavior that you should never rely on.

Comment: What sources are telling you this is undefined? It's fully documented. You can expect a response on everything except for an HTTP timeout or connection failure... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.response.aspx

Comment: What are my sources? experience... This isn't something I would suggest. It relies on the sever providing a response in the stream which is rarely guaranteed.