# How do I get the HTTP response from a navigation to a page?

Tags: c#, http, http-headers, http-status-code-404

I have a scenario where I navigate to a test site, but for whatever reason (connectivity issues, etc), sometimes, the test fails because it couldn't reach the website. How do I ask for the HTTP header? I'm looking to check if it's a 404, obviously, but I haven't dealt with headers before.

Language of choice is C#, but I'm open.

Thanks for looking.

Comment: Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074707/how-do-i-get-headers-from-a-401-server-error/9074799#9074799 It is about inspecting headers for a 401, but 404's will be the same.

Comment: How do you send requests to the site?  It is not clear whether you already have code for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an [HttpRequest](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=httpwebrequest+tutorial) (I'm not showing code for brevity), then set `HttpMethod = "HEAD"` and when you call [GetResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx) method do something like this

```
try{
    req.GetResponse();
} catch(WebException ex) {
    if (ex.Response != null)
        //Server explicit problem (ie. 404)
    else
        //Network problem: server wasn't even hit
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[FiddlerCore](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/Core/). It allows you to monitor/modify your application's HTTP traffic. This is if you are using a browser.

You could always send a HTTP Head request before the browser navigates if you want to check the status of the site.

Comment: I've used Fiddler, it's awesome. That being said, my solution needs to be programmatic.

Answer (score 0):

Just try send basic HTTP request before redirecting to the page. Simply check if the webiste returns 200OK response and then redirect. Hope this example helps: `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse%28v=vs.71%29.aspx`